# Changing body of function during compilation in C

Tags: c, function, directive, conditional-compilation

Assume I have a function like below:

```
void func1(...) {
    ...
    ...
    func2(...);
    ...
    ...
}
```

In the compilation phase, I call the `func1()` function in two places. However, in one of the places I don't want the `func2()` to be executed.

So, I need two versions of `func1()` during **compilation**: one **with** `func2()` and one **without** `func2()`.

I know about following approaches. They require deforming the current source, which I hesitate to do

1. Putting the whole body of function in `#define` -> then defining two functions with different names using this macro.
2. Putting the body of the function into another header file and using `#define` macros to control the execution path.

Do you know any other methods besides above methods?

Comment: 3. define `func2()` as a macro.  Control whether the function is called by varying the definition of that macro.

Comment: Simply do not use the same name if processing should not be the same. You certainly can achieve that terrible requirement with macros, but maintenance will be a nightmare!

Comment: Provide `func1` with an additional parameter telling it whether to execute `func2`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: It is a good approach but it needs an `if` statement that puts a heavy burden on my platform. That is why I am avoiding `if`s by using compilation flags to make runtime execution more smoother (by reducing branches).

Answer (score 4):

A pretty common way is to define a token and wrap the call in an `#ifdef` block (checking for the token), no need to duplicate `func1` i.e. :

```
#define _INCLUDE_FUNC2_BUILD// or something

void func1(...) {
    ...
    ...
#ifdef _INCLUDE_FUNC2_BUILD
    func2(...);
#endif // _INCLUDE_FUNC2_BUILD
    ...
    ...
}
```

Obviously it's up to you how/where you want to include the `#define` you could use something like [Jam](https://www.perforce.com/resources/documentation/jam).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when the `func1` is compiled, its body is fixed to either have `func2` or not. I can not change the body for the rest of the compilations. Consider this: `foo(){ ...; func1();...;}`    and    `bar(){...;func1();...;}`. I want the `func2()` be executed in `foo` and not in `bar`.

Comment: @Millad I'm not sure what you mean exactly, with this approach, `func2()` itself is not compiled out, only the call goes ( the nice thing is, while not guaranteed, some compilers will compile the function itself out if no calls to it exist ). If you wanted `func2()` to exist as a call in `foo()` and not `bar()`, just `#ifdef` it out of `bar()` and leave it in `foo()`. You can also use conditionals the defined directive if you wanted to include a `func2()` call somewhere but only with certain builds, something like `#if defined(_BUILD_A) || defined(_BUILD_B)`

Comment: When compiler tries to compile this code, it reaches the `func1()` once and based on whether `_INCLUDE_FUNC2_BUILD` is defined or not, the `func1` is compiled. From now on, the body of `func1` is fixed and designated. It cannot be changed. Therefore, for the parts of the code that `func1` is called, we can not control when `func2` should be called.

Comment: Are you saying that you want `func2` to be called based on where `func1` is called from at runtime?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. For some specific calls of `func1`, I do not want to run `func2`. For the rest, I DO want to run `func2`. To emphasis, I need to it in C, not C++.

Comment: Note that names starting with an underscore and followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.  Simply do not create such names; only use them when you're following the documentation of 'the implementation'.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than conditional compilation, especially if the rest of the function is substantial, you can pass a parameter to indicate whether `func2()` should be called.  The function might be defined as:

```
void func1(..., bool call_func2) {
    ...
    ...
    if (call_func2)
        func2(...);
    ...
    ...
}
```

and one call might be `func1(..., true)` and the other `func1(..., false)`.

If you decide you sometimes need to call `func2()`, and sometimes `func3()`, and sometimes nothing, you might change the function parameter into a pointer to function:

```
void func1(..., void (*funcN)(...)) {
    ...
    ...
    if (funcN)
        funcN(...);
    ...
    ...
}
```

and then you can have `func1(..., func2)`, `func1(..., func3)`, and `func1(..., NULL)`.  Ring the changes to suit.  Note that the function pointer scheme assumes that the `funcN` functions have a uniform interface.

Otherwise, look to see whether you need to refactor the function.

```
void func1A(...) {
    ...
    ...
    ...before call to func2...
}

void func1B(...) {
    ...after call to func2...
    ...
    ...
}

void func1(...) {
    func1A(...);
    func1B(...);
}

void func1plus2(...) {
    func1A(...);
    func2(...);
    func1B(...);
}
```

These are all better than `#ifdef` conditional compilation.  In the first instance, I'd probably go with the flag variable in the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the approaches. I am working in an environment that `if` statements are heavy statements and need to be avoided. The second approach is also using function pointers which is completely prohibited. However, you last approach makes more sense ans as you said is much more better. However, it needs more extensive code rewriting, which I am avoiding.

Comment: Conduct the measurements; I would be modestly surprised if testing the conditions were sufficiently measurable.  If they are, then you probably are going to have to go with `#ifdef` hackers. Unless the function is used in separate executables, you will need two names for it — one for with the call and one without.  But I worry about your code's maintainability.